# Issue with dependency in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, maven, jpa

I know that the `orphanRemoval` attribute is present in `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` and this is the library being used in my project.

I added the Maven dependency:

> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>     <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
> </dependency>
> ```

And I'm still getting the error: `The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type OneToMany` in the line:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "id.store", cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, orphanRemoval=true)
```

What is the problem here, and what can I do to troubleshoot this problem?

**EDIT:** These are my dependencies:

> ```
> <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
>         <version>${jersey-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
>         <version>${jersey-version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>junit</groupId>
>         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
>         <version>4.8.2</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>         <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
>         <version>${jersey-version}</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.distributions</groupId>
>         <artifactId>web-all</artifactId>
>         <version>10.0-build-20080430</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
>         <artifactId>gf-embedded-api</artifactId>
>         <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
>         <scope>test</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
>         <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
>         <version>2.5</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
>        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
>     </dependency>
> </dependencies>
> ```

Comment: It was in `hibernate-jpa-2.0` as well, ie. Java EE 6. Are you sure you are using `javax.persistence.OneToMany`?

Comment: Add the error stack trace to have better idea.

Comment: @suresh It's a compilation error. It's there.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your dependencies?

Comment: Yes, the import `javax.persistence.OneToMany` is there. And I checked the Maven dependency tree in my project, it contains `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar`. I also have checked inside the class `OneToMany`. It contains `cascade`, `fetch`, `mappedBy`, `orphanRemoval`, and `targetEntity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The glassfish web-all dependency also contain the JPA packages, and it contains an old version of it (from 2008-04-30 as the version of the artefact indicates, so probably JPA 1.0).

You can see the packages included in this dependency here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.distributions/web-all/10.0-build-20080430.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed the reference and it worked. Since I used eclipse to build the project and used the `jersey-quickstart-webapp` archetype, it automatically included that reference. As this is my first Maven project, I didn't know what was wrong.

Comment: My small experience with Maven artefacts has shown that almost all of them are obsolete, and shouldn't be used. You'd better carefully choose your dependencies. And I would also suggest learnig gradle instead of Maven: it's a far superior build tool, that handles dependencies from Maven repositories just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Added `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar` and removed `persistence.jar` that didn't have `orphanRemoval()` method in `javax.persistence` package in Referenced Libraries. That solved the error

> "The attribute orphanRemoval is undefined for the annotation type
>   OneToMany".

Comment: It is available in this jar - hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar